# Facebook user profile link not returned in API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth

Here is the scope used: email, public_profile, user_link,  user_birthday, user_hometown, user_location
Here are the fields applied, fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,link,gender,locale,about,email,hometown,location,birthday

For some users the "link" attribute is not returned. Why is this?

Comment: Did they actually grant the permission?

Comment: Yes, I test it by using my own 2 Facebook accounts. One of them got profile url returned in "link" attributes. The other one didn't.

Comment: Where else the user can set the permission for sharing profile url?

Comment: They either grant it when your app asks for it during login, or they don’t. Make a request for `/me/permissions` using their access token and check, if you are not sure.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to identify the problem. I found my scope in configuration file was overwritten, and the scope for user_link is missing.